# Can anyone help to fix the issue with my python batch file? CMD is showing blank screen at the first instance

Tags: python, sql, batch-file

I have a batch file which is sheduled to run every day. (A python script)

Some times, when it runs in the first instance it runs and shows only a CMD blank screen for long time. Nothing happens. If we close it and run the batch file again, it says the task is completed press any key to continue.

Why this file isnt working in the first instance? Can anyone help?

The below is my bat. file

```
@echo off
"C:\Users\snyder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" "C:\Users\snyder\OneDrive\Documents\Python Scripts\AutoRun\RD_Data.py"
pause
```

Can anyone please help?

These are the contents of my RD_Data.py filr

```
import pypyodbc as odbc
import cursor
import requests
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\sahan\Desktop\Empdata.xlsx')


columns = ['nameX', 'id', 'mark', 'department'] 
        
df_data = df[columns]
records = df_data.values.tolist()

DRIVER = 'SQL Server'
SERVER_NAME = 'LAPTOP-DIVPVC2Q\SQLEXPRESS'
DATABASE_NAME = 'CSE'

def connection_string(driver, server_name, database_name):
    conn_string = f"""
        DRIVER={{{driver}}};
        SERVER={server_name};
        DATABASE={database_name};
        Trust_Connection=yes;        
    """
    return conn_string

try:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(sql_insert, records)
    cursor.commit();    
except Exception as e:
    cursor.rollback()
    print(str(e[1]))
finally:
    print('Task is complete.')
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Yes its .py file which pluggs data in to sql. It reads a file and exports data under a scheduled time. but the batch file is not working. in the first instance it shows only a blank screen.

Comment: How do you have this scheduled?  Did you create the scheduled task to run as user "sahan"?  By default, scheduled tasks run as a system user that won't have access to your files.

Comment: Well I have downloaded an external alternative called System scheduler. Because windows task scheduler isnt working with my pc and it need to run manually. If we give time to run itself, it wont run. What we have to do is right click it and do a manual run.

Comment: The current RD_Data.py shown is definitely broken - I'm guessing it is a snippet/modified version.   As Chris says can you get a small reproducible example.   It would be good to see the output from a manual run.   In the exception print the exception straight away do not run another command as that might have its own exception.

Comment: @SnyderFox, I have fixed the formatting issue with your batch file. The reason was because you had included a line feed, not because of spaces.